# What is a Pool Class in Java?

Tags: java, android, class, object, pool

I don't understand what pool, pool object factory, and 'free object' are in Java. I'm learning java for use in android, and I came across a Pool class. I have searched the internet and found they are used for recycling, and to save memory is what I gathered, but I don't understand how exactly. I am new to Java.

Comment: Example : When an object takes time to instantiate and when response time is critic (e.g. a database connection), having a pool allows to shortcut instantiation time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pools serve multiple purposes, e.g.

- reusing objects without having to destroy and recreate them
- restricting the number of objects created
- etc.

Suppose you have need an object of type A. Instead of calling `new A()` to create it and removing the references or destroying the object when you don't need it anymore you ask a pool of A to give you an instance and you hand it back when you don't need it. In that case the pool decides whether to create or reuse a new instance, what to do if no more "free" instances are left and what to do when an instance is given back (released).

Comment: Oh, thank you. But what is a poolfactory? And I gather from what you said that by making a Pool of A, I can create multiple instances of A simultaneously as well?

Comment: A pool factory would be a factory class that creates a pool of A and handles the details for you, i.e. you'd most probably just pass a bunch of parameters and/or select the type of factory and let it create a pool for you (hint: google "factory pattern"). A pool of A would allow you to have multiple instances of A, how many would depend on the settings of the pool.

Comment: What is the practical difference between a `SimplePool` and a `SynchronizedPool`?

Comment: @Suragch you might probably want to provide some more information about which classes you mean (e.g. the library) but from the names there should be at least one obvious difference: `SynchronizedPool` should be synchronized and thus threadsafe but also a tad slower.

Answer (score 1):

when a lot number of client(program) access a resource than pooling comes into action. Let there are 5 active channel to access that resource and at a time 6 user is trying to access that resource than 6th resource will be rejected and the application accessing resource data will show connection failure. But if we use pooling than 6th will be waiting for certain time defined in Pooling configuration and if by that time if resource is released by any of the clients than resource will be accessible to 6th user and connection will not be rejected.
Max number of waiting client max time waiting are the configuration parameter.

Comment: Why would an application without pooling reject the connection? It most probably would use a pool to check the number of free connections and in many cases when the pool is empty it isn't the pool that blocks but the application that reacts to the pool being empty.